# SQL Join query assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Currently, I have 2 queries:

```
SELECT dateadd(month, x.MonthOffset,0) as [Month], SUM(x.itemcount) as [Total] FROM
    ( SELECT datediff(month,0, cna.impdate) as MonthOffset, count(*) as itemcount FROM myTable
      WHERE (emergency = 'Emergency') AND (impdate BETWEEN '" + fromDate + "' AND '" + toDate + "') 
      GROUP BY impdate ) x
      GROUP BY MonthOffset ORDER BY MonthOffset asc

SELECT dateadd(month, x.MonthOffset,0) as [Month], SUM(x.itemcount) as [Total] FROM
    ( SELECT datediff(month,0, cna.impdate) as MonthOffset, count(*) as itemcount FROM myTable
      WHERE (impdate BETWEEN '" + fromDate + "' AND '" + toDate + "') 
      GROUP BY impdate ) x
      GROUP BY MonthOffset ORDER BY MonthOffset asc
```

This will return 2 columns of data with a monthly count of items.

My problem occurs when there exists a month without an emergency item.  Because I pass the object through to the second query, if the number of columns retrieved from the first does not match the second, I will receive an index out of bounds error.

How can I join my two queries together so that I can have 3 columns - month, emergency total and item total?  Emergency total can be 0 or null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a way of testing it but I think this should give you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT dateadd(month, datediff(month,0, cna.impdate),0) as [Month], 
       count(*) as itemcount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN emergency = 'Emergency' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EmergencyCount
FROM myTable
WHERE impdate BETWEEN '" + fromDate + "' AND '" + toDate + "'
GROUP BY dateadd(month, datediff(month,0, cna.impdate),0)
ORDER BY [Month] asc
```

Comment: Good offer that it puts both counts and how many were emergencies all in one row per month.  Should be very simple for yookd to do whatever else he needs...

Comment: I didn't know about the CASE expression. Thank you, it's simple and elegant.